# Maps: avoiding unpaved roads?

Tags: iphone, ios, maps

Is there a way to get Maps (iPhone 17.2) to avoid unpaved roads?  I don’t see anything relevant in Settings.

I recently visited my parents, and my phone kept insisting on taking me down various dirt roads (in the rain!) when there was a completely paved option that added less than a mile to my -300 mile trip.

Comment: I don't believe so, but you can report the directions as being bad. Bring up bad directions but instead of tapping "GO" tap the rest of the row to see the step-by-step. Scroll to the bottom and tap Report an Issue. You can then select where it turns onto the dirt road and choose "something else"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - you can avoid highways but not dirt roads in Apple Maps as a routing preference.

In cities, maps tends to find the main streets in a neighborhood and chooses those based on travel time optimizations (both entered by the mapping companies and crowd sourced) but in rural areas, speed doesn’t always map to paved status.

Look for “fewer turns” options when you map, but I think you would have to change your destination to be on the paved road to trick the calculation to offer non dirt options.